# Installing factoextra package in R

Tags: r

I am using R version >3.5. I want to install *factoextra* package on R studio (I use Mac). I tried to install the package directly with dependencies = TRUE, and I also tried to install the dependencies packages one by one. Neither worked.

Here is the error message: (* represents the user on my computer).

```
* installing *source* package ‘quantreg’ ...
** package ‘quantreg’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
/Users/*/.R/Makevars:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘quantreg’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/quantreg’
* installing *source* package ‘mclust’ ...
** package ‘mclust’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
/Users/*/.R/Makevars:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mclust’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/mclust’
ERROR: dependencies ‘pbkrtest’, ‘quantreg’ are not available for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/car’
ERROR: dependency ‘car’ is not available for package ‘rstatix’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rstatix’
ERROR: dependency ‘rstatix’ is not available for package ‘ggpubr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/ggpubr’
ERROR: dependency ‘ggpubr’ is not available for package ‘factoextra’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/factoextra’
```

The downloaded source packages are in:

```
‘/private/var/folders/8v/mfj4t9t54y72cdrz6q84jnjh0000gn/T/RtmpfEwO54/downloaded_packages’
```

Warning messages:

```
1: In install.packages("factoextra", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘quantreg’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("factoextra", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘mclust’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("factoextra", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("factoextra", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘rstatix’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("factoextra", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘ggpubr’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages("factoextra", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘factoextra’ had non-zero exit status
```

> any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: hi, I have the same I think... do you have also a line with `CMake Error: The source directory "/tmp/..." does not exist.` ? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

R packages come in two shapes: as pre-compiled binaries, and as source code. In your case, it seems that the compilation of mclust and quantreg failed, as suggested by the error message

```
Stop. ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mclust’
Stop. ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘quantreg’
```

You could try to force install them from binary by running: `install.packages("mclust", type = "binary")` and `install.packages("quantreg", type = "binary")`