# Can't install nloptr package for R on CentOS 7

Tags: r, centos

I am encountering the same type of problem as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71250259/cannot-install-r-package-cmake-errorr). However, in accordance with the answer, I have updated my R (version 4.1.3) and CMake (version 3.12.3) and I still can't seem to install the package. I am running CentOS 7.

Here is the log:

```
> install.packages("nloptr")
Installing package into ‘/home/userr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/nloptr_2.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2219414 bytes (2.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘nloptr’ ...
** package ‘nloptr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -std=gnu++11 -E
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking if pkg-config knows NLopt... no
using NLopt via local cmake build on x86_64 
set CMAKE_BIN=/usr/local/bin/cmake
set CC=gcc -std=gnu11
set CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include -fpic -g -O2
set CXX=g++
set CXXFLAGS=-std=gnu++11 -I/usr/local/include -fpic -g -O2
set LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib
CMake Error: The source directory "/tmp/RtmpVJjt9p/R.INSTALL27cf4036808b/nloptr/src/nlopt-build" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
Error: /tmp/RtmpVJjt9p/R.INSTALL27cf4036808b/nloptr/src/nlopt-build is not a directory
CMake Error: The source directory "/tmp/RtmpVJjt9p/R.INSTALL27cf4036808b/nloptr/src/nlopt" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
cp: cannot stat 'nlopt/include/*': No such file or directory
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
gcc -std=gnu11 -I"/opt/R/4.1.3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include  -I'/home/userr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/testthat/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c init_nloptr.c -o init_nloptr.o
gcc -std=gnu11 -I"/opt/R/4.1.3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include  -I'/home/userr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/testthat/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c nloptr.c -o nloptr.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/opt/R/4.1.3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include  -I'/home/userr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/testthat/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c test-C-API.cpp -o test-C-API.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/opt/R/4.1.3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include  -I'/home/userr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/testthat/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c test-runner.cpp -o test-runner.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/opt/R/4.1.3/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o nloptr.so init_nloptr.o nloptr.o test-C-API.o test-runner.o -L/opt/R/4.1.3/lib/R/lib -lRlapack -L/opt/R/4.1.3/lib/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -Lnlopt/lib -lnlopt -L/opt/R/4.1.3/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/userr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-nloptr/00new/nloptr/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package ‘nloptr’
    finding HTML links ... done
    auglag                                  html  
    bobyqa                                  html  
    ccsaq                                   html  
    check.derivatives                       html  
    cobyla                                  html  
    crs2lm                                  html  
    direct                                  html  
    is.nloptr                               html  
    isres                                   html  
    lbfgs                                   html  
    mlsl                                    html  
    mma                                     html  
    neldermead                              html  
    newuoa                                  html  
    nl.grad                                 html  
    nl.opts                                 html  
    nloptr-package                          html  
    nloptr                                  html  
    nloptr.get.default.options              html  
    nloptr.print.options                    html  
    print.nloptr                            html  
    sbplx                                   html  
    slsqp                                   html  
    stogo                                   html  
    tnewton                                 html  
    varmetric                               html  
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘nloptr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/userr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-nloptr/00new/nloptr/libs/nloptr.so':
  libnlopt.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/userr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/nloptr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp3kX1wu/downloaded_packages’
```

I don't know what could be causing the error, but my guess is that this line from the above log is the most relevant:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/tmp/RtmpVJjt9p/R.INSTALL27cf4036808b/nloptr/src/nlopt-build" does not exist.
```

I would be thankful for all the help as I don't know much about Linux systems.

Comment: This has come up before at the GitHub issues. You need at least `cmake` version 3.15, and there are ways to get it for your somewhat aged CentOS system.

Comment: From the EPEL repo  https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/ : `# yum install cmake3` → Provides cmake-3.17 . ..... The new cmake command is then e.g. `cmake3 ../`

Comment: Updated to cmake 3.23 and now it works, thanks. Please add the comment as an answer so other people can see it more easily. The answer in the previous question makes it seem like it's sufficient to install just any version of cmake >= 3, which no longer seems to be true. I did not even know that newer versions than 3.12 exist